# Using bit shift with SPI data in processing

Tags: processing, raspberry-pi3, bit-shift, spi, adc

For a research project that I'm doing for my chemistry lab we are using and ADS8320 chip (Data Sheet found [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads8320.pdf). We are using this to take in voltage readings with a potentiometer through the SPI pins on a Raspberry Pi 3. While I have been able to get data using [this code](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/io/SPI.html) from Processing.org:

```
import processing.io.*;
SPI adc;

void setup() {
  //printArray(SPI.list());
  adc = new SPI(SPI.list()[0]);
  adc.settings(500000, SPI.MSBFIRST, SPI.MODE0);
}

void draw() {
  // read in values over SPI from an analog-to-digital
  // converter
  // dummy write, actual values don't matter
  byte[] out = { 0, 0 };
  byte[] in = adc.transfer(out);
  // some input bit shifting according to the datasheet
  int val = ((in[0] & 0x1f) << 5) | ((in[1] & 0xf8) >> 3);
  // val is between 0 and 1023
  println(val);
}
```

From what I read on the data sheet I should be getting a value of 65535 when taking in the max voltage. Instead I am getting a value of 127 when taking in max voltage. I'm not by any means a good programmer having picked it up almost exactly a month ago, but I think the issue lies in the bit shift line of code:

```
int val = ((in[0] & 0x1f) << 5) | ((in[1] & 0xf8) >> 3);
```

if this is the issue how would I set it to work with my 16 bit ADS chip? Could you also explain what this bit shift actually is for, as every source I found on it just made me more confused. Any help on this would be insanely helpful! Also if I am missing any critical information please let me know, as again I am still pretty new at this.

Comment: You'll have better luck if you [debug your program](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) and narrow your problem down to a [mcve]. What is the value if `in[0]` and `in[1]`? Are they what you expect? Split that complicated line into multiple steps. Which steps is behaving differently from what you expected? Then if you get stuck, you can post a [mcve] of just those couple lines without all of the extra data reading stuff. Just hardcode the values instead.

Comment: Awesome I will split that down and see if I can't get a value. The line was very complicated and confused me a ton. I'll split it up and see if I cant get a working code, or at least have a better more concise example for you.

Comment: According to page 24 of the data sheet, you might need to read in 3 bytes instead of 2, discarding the first 6 bits and the last two bits. As a result, your bit shift expression will change to something like ```int val = ((in[0] & 0x03) << 14) | (in[1] << 6) | (in[2] & 0x3f);``` Wikipedia talks about [bitwise operations in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Shift_operators) including bit shift operations.

Comment: Thank you! I've headed home from the lab where I can try this today. I'll try this out first thing tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: @v1bri thank you for letting me know about the 3 bytes. I tried your code and got some weird negative numbers. Im not sure why this is, could it be from the 0x03 and 0x3f that you added to bytes in[0] and in[2]?

Comment: Yep hence the "something like" (: Print out the raw values that are being read and see if you can use the datasheet to understand what the ADC is sending back.

Comment: Awesome, I have a much better idea of whats going on now I think, Thank you so much for the help! It makes a lot more sense than it did a day ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line of the code is how you read your 10 bit value from the chip. input 0 (in[0]) has the 5 most significant bits of your data and input 1 (in[1]) has the 5 least significant bits. Hence, the shift operation. Imagine your data has 10 bits, you do (0b00011111 AND Input[0]) and you shift it to left by 5. Then you do (0b11111000 AND Input[1]) and shift it to right by 3. At the end, when putting them together with OR `val1 | val2`, you will be left with a 10 bit value. However, if you visit the data sheet of your chip, your chip is a 16 bit ADC, which means you migh need another pins to read the extra 6 bits you are not reading. Furthermore, make sure you are connecting correct pins to in[0] and in[1] as it can revers the orientation of your bit streams.